# Работа с файлами из быстрого доступа

Tags: python, windows, файлы, файловая-система

В windows в проводнике есть раздел `быстрый доступ` как я могу обратиться к файлам из быстрого доступа? Они же по сути там не хранятся, а просто указывают путь на файл. Как мне получить эти пути к файлам с помущью `python` или с помощью системных команд `windows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Последние файлы находятся здесь: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

Answer (score 0):

на аналогичный вопрос в англоязычном SO в комментариях написали, что для решения отсутствует описание API от производителя (для папки `Quick Access`).
Отсюда, я полагаю, лучше решать средствами GUI - через shell.

Вот один из примеров "тупой" VBscript реализации.
Запускаем Проводник, открывая нужный каталог. А затем, подождав полсекунды, получаем список файлов в последнем открытом окне.

```
'-------------quick_access-list.vbs
'Создаем объект оболочки
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Запускаем Проводник, открывая нужный объект 
objShell.Run("explorer.exe shell:::{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}")
'выжидаем полсекунды
WScript.Sleep 500

'Создаем объект для управления оболочкой
Set objShellAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Найдя последнее окно, обращаемся к его свойству document
With objShellAPP.Windows(objShellAPP.Windows.Count - 1).document
'Проходим в цикле по всем объектам документа окна
    For Each FileItem In .Folder.Items
'Выводим в цикле путь к каждому объекту
       WScript.Echo FileItem.Path
    Next
End With
```

P.S. Хотелось бы увидеть решение от автора вопроса на Python.
А чтобы получить перечень в консоль, а не в виде множества сообщений подсистемы Windows Script Host, рекомендую запускать скрипт командой:
`cscript //nologo quick_access-list.vbs`